# Should [svn] and [subversion] be tag synonyms?

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms, tag-merge

- [svn](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/svn) has 71 questions with a wiki summary.
- [subversion](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/subversion) has 29 questions but no wiki summary.

Should [subversion](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/subversion) map to [svn](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/svn)?

If yes, please could someone with enough rep do so?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The same mapping exists on Stack Overflow so I've gone ahead and done this.

Comment: Thank you, Chris!